# jsf messages enqueued and not display

Tags: validation, jsf

I have a jsf Form with fields, submit and messages for it

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
    <h:outputText value="Введите логин и пароль:"/>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-Mail:"/>
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{sign.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Введите e-mail" validatorMessage="email должен быть вида abc@abc.abc">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:"/>
        <h:inputSecret converter="pwdConverter" id="password" value="#{sign.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Введите пароль"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{sign.doLogin()}" value="Войти"/>
        <h:commandLink action="/pages/register?faces-redirect=true" immediate="true" value="Зарегистрироваться"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:messages for="loginForm"/>
</h:form>
```

And it works fine: when I just click on the submit without input anything, it shows me a validation erros, but when I added a facebook-login button, I have a message in server log: `Info:   WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=loginForm:email[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Введите e-mail), detail=(Введите e-mail)]` for each field and validation messages not displayed on the page any more
there is how I added a fb-button:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="login.js"/>
<h:form id="loginForm">
    <h:outputText value="Введите логин и пароль:"/>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="E-Mail:"/>
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{sign.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Введите e-mail" validatorMessage="email должен быть вида abc@abc.abc">
            <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:"/>
        <h:inputSecret converter="pwdConverter" id="password" value="#{sign.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Введите пароль"/>
        <h:commandButton action="#{sign.doLogin()}" value="Войти"/>
        <h:commandLink action="/pages/register?faces-redirect=true" immediate="true" value="Зарегистрироваться"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:messages for="loginForm"/>
</h:form>
<br/>

    <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
    <div id="status"/>
```

Comment: in the login.js there is an example javascript code from facebook tutorial and it works

Comment: The `for` attribute of `<h:messages/>` takes an identifier of the component for which messages are to be displayed. You have currently specified the identifier of `<h:form>`. Thus, no message component is found to show the rendered message(s) hence, the warning. Just remove the `for` attribute  or mention the identifier of the component of your interest or use separate `<h:message>` component with a `for` attribute to show error messages associated with each component independently instead.

Comment: @Tiny please move that comment into an answer. OP, make sure to accept the answer by clicking the check below the arrows of reputation.